# Under IIS installation features, what is the difference between .net framework 4.7 and asp.net 4.7

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, .net-framework-version, windows-server-2019

Under IIS installation features, what is the difference between .net framework 4.7 and asp.net 4.7

[image]

Comment: obviously, Asp.net is seen here as one of the features of .net framework

Comment: What is the difference between `.net framework 4.7` (option 1) and `asp.net 4.7` (option 2)?

Comment: asp.net is the web tool for .net framework

Comment: You mean to deploy a .NET website on IIS I need to enable ASP.NET 4.7?

Comment: yes. you need asp.net component for IIS to run Asp.net applications

Comment: Can you tell me 1 reason why someone will install IIS but not checkmark the ASP.NET 4.7?

Comment: Simply because IIS is not only for ASP.NET, so people do install IIS without ASP.NET.

Comment: @variable I think you need to ask this to microsoft. IIS can have all sorts of apps. CGI, html-only, ftp, classic asp, and much more. if you need to run Asp.net app - you must register this framework with IIS. Thats all. And if you want to run .net core on IIS, you have another separate integration component to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Framework 4.7 installs just the framework itself on the system.

ASP.NET 4.7 is equivalent to the command line of `aspnet_regiis -i` which registers ASP.NET bits on IIS,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-2.0/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.80)

Such separation of core framework/ASP.NET/WCF (backed by `ServiceModelReg.exe`) has been widely known since .NET Framework 1.0, but sounds like that knowledge has been lost after two decades.